# how to post data from angular service to laravel controller

Tags: angularjs, laravel, angularjs-service

this is my angular controller which i use it in laravel  but when i submit my form i get

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException

```
app.service('post_service', function ($http) {

    create = $http.POST('/post', JSON.stringify(data)).then(
       function mySuccess(response) {
           debugger
           $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
       },
       function myError(response) {
           debugger
           $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
       }
    )
});


app.controller('postController', ['$scope', function ($scope, post_service) {
    $scope.message = 'AddPosts';
    // $scope.post=null;
    $scope.save = function (data) {
        post_service.create(data)
    }
}]);
```

my route config is this :

```
Route::resource('post', 'PostController');
```

like you see i using resource controller which allow us to use all type of routing like store index or....

for more detail: my form is simple angular form which contains no token string like **`csrfToken`** or some thing like that

Comment: why you have /post/store i think you should have only /post and based on your method it will automatically fire the function in laravel controller

Comment: @GauravSrivastava still not working

Comment: You are using store method in PostController for the api?

Comment: public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return $request;
    }
@GauravSrivastava

Comment: what's the output of `php artisan route:list | grep post` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the this `Route::post('/postData', 'PostController@action');`

in the angular service

```
$http.POST('/postData', JSON.stringify(data)).then(

code here 
);
```